# Ul sector moves to the left

Tags: html, css, web, conditional-operator

I want move All ul section to left .

it means that ul section (second section of menu

) in this picture Be opened in left

menu instead of right.

please help me.

[my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDTN0.png)

[my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OpGW.jpg)

```css
.cd-dropdown-content,.cd-dropdown-content ul  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //open/close mega-navigation
 $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleNav();
 });

 //close meganavigation
 $('.cd-dropdown .cd-close').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleNav();
 });

 //on mobile - open submenu
 $('.has-children').children('a').on('click', function(event){
  //prevent default clicking on direct children of .has-children 
  event.preventDefault();
  var selected = $(this);
  selected.next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('move-out');
 });

 //on desktop - differentiate between a user trying to hover over a dropdown item vs trying to navigate into a submenu's contents
 var submenuDirection = ( !$('.cd-dropdown-wrapper').hasClass('open-to-left') ) ? 'right' : 'left';
 $('.cd-dropdown-content').menuAim({
        activate: function(row) {
         $(row).children().addClass('is-active').removeClass('fade-out');
         if( $('.cd-dropdown-content .fade-in').length == 0 ) $(row).children('ul').addClass('fade-in');
        },
        deactivate: function(row) {
         $(row).children().removeClass('is-active');
         if( $('li.has-children:hover').length == 0 || $('li.has-children:hover').is($(row)) ) {
          $('.cd-dropdown-content').find('.fade-in').removeClass('fade-in');
          $(row).children('ul').addClass('fade-out')
         }
        },
        exitMenu: function() {
         $('.cd-dropdown-content').find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
         return true;
        },
        submenuDirection: submenuDirection,
    });

 //submenu items - go back link
 $('.go-back').on('click', function(){
  var selected = $(this),
   visibleNav = $(this).parent('ul').parent('.has-children').parent('ul');
  selected.parent('ul').addClass('is-hidden').parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('move-out');
 }); 

 function toggleNav(){
  var navIsVisible = ( !$('.cd-dropdown').hasClass('dropdown-is-active') ) ? true : false;
  $('.cd-dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
  $('.cd-dropdown-trigger').toggleClass('dropdown-is-active', navIsVisible);
  if( !navIsVisible ) {
   $('.cd-dropdown').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
    $('.has-children ul').addClass('is-hidden');
    $('.move-out').removeClass('move-out');
    $('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
   }); 
  }
 }

 //IE9 placeholder fallback
 //credits http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
 if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
  $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
   var input = $(this);
   if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
     }
  }).blur(function() {
    var input = $(this);
     if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
     }
  }).blur();
  $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
     $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }
     })
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the solution for your problem..  Hope its helpful

  <!--- HTML -->   
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Main menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
    <!-- End HTML -->

    /** CSS **/

        .dropdown-menu{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 10px;
          list-style: none;
          background-color: #dddddd;
          max-width:300px;
          width: auto;
          display: inline-block;
          margin-left: 200px;
          position:relative;
        }

        .dropdown-menu li , .dropdown-submenu li{
          padding: 5px;           
        }
        .dropdown-menu li a{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #ff0000; 
        }
        .dropdown-submenu li a{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #fff;
        }
        .dropdown-submenu {
          position: absolute;  
          list-style:none;
          background-color: red;
          color:#fff;
          margin:0;
          padding: 10px;
          z-index:2;
          width: 100%;
          top:0;
          right:100%;  
        }

   /** End CSS **/
```

here is the link [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/practice123/zbcyrgq6/)